# How to have same variables in different methods? How to call an instance method in a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

First, I have two methods and basically the same variables. How can I shorten this:

```
def one
  humba = "was"
  que = "como"
  ruz = 12
  ....
end

def two
  humba = "was"
  que = "como"
  ....
end
```

I'd also like to know how to call a method in my model? I have for example this method in my model:

```
def model_def
end
```

And in my controller I want to write something like this:

```
tmp = params[:setting][:file].tempfile
doc = DBF::Table.new(tmp)
model_def(doc)
```

Comment: Could you try to ask just one question per post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you are asking. But generally, you would store shared variables in instance variables inside a class:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author

  def description
    "#{@title} was written by #{@author}."
  end
end
```

To answer your question "how can I make a def to point to my model" I assume you mean "how can I call a method on my model: Well, you create an instance of the object. In Rails, it could be something like this:

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@book.author = "A New Author" # to make an assignment
```

To read an attribute, you could just do this:

```
@book = Book.find(params[:id])
@book.author => "Ernest Hemingway"
```

In your case:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :humba, :que, :ruz
end
```

This lets you do things like:

```
@foo = Foo.new
@foo.humba = "que"
@foo.humba => "que"
```